# Repetitive Password code

Tags: python

I am trying to create a password generator. I have succeeded in creating a functional code but it keeps on showing how it generates the passwords instead of just giving three lines as shown:

This is my code:

```
def Generate(): #menu function, Generates a password
    global password
    print("Generating...")

    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()?" #These are the avaliable characters available to the password

    length = input("password length?") #asks for how long the user wants their password

    if int(length) < 25: #Doesn't allow the code to print over 26 characters        

        length = int(length)


        for p in range(3):

            password = " "

            for c in range(length): #for loop which 

                password += random.choice(chars) #randomly choses characters at random to create the password

                print(password)

    else:
       print ("The password can only be between 8-24 characterss long")
       Generate ()
```

This is my program running:

```
Generating...
password length?14
*
*C
*CD
*CDb
*CDbF
*CDbFA
*CDbFAi
*CDbFAiK
*CDbFAiKk
*CDbFAiKkA
*CDbFAiKkAa
*CDbFAiKkAa9
*CDbFAiKkAa9m
*CDbFAiKkAa9mr
7
7Y
7Ys
7Ysy
7Ysyj
7Ysyjj
7Ysyjj2
7Ysyjj28
7Ysyjj28C
7Ysyjj28Ch
7Ysyjj28Chq
7Ysyjj28Chqk
7Ysyjj28Chqk(
7Ysyjj28Chqk(k
E
E%
E%C
E%C8
E%C8(
E%C8(w
E%C8(w7
E%C8(w7M
E%C8(w7Mj
E%C8(w7MjP
E%C8(w7MjPO
E%C8(w7MjPOz
E%C8(w7MjPOzx
E%C8(w7MjPOzxx
```

Could you please help me to make the code just output three words?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Move `print(password)` out of that inner loop.

Comment: I've moved it to the end of the outer loop, after Generate(). It only gives me one "word" but I will work on that. Thank-You.

Comment: BTW, it looks like you need to add a test to make sure the password isn't too short.

Comment: @PM2Ring , what do you mean by this?

Comment: There is so much things we could help you out here than just what you asked for actually!

Comment: @d-coder, go on... I'm listening....

Comment: I didn't mean that you need to move the `print(password)` line, you just needed to change its indentation so it's still inside the `for p in range(3):` loop, but _not_ inside the `for c in range(length):` loop, as Jack's answer shows.

Comment: You test that the length < 25, but you also need to test that length > 7.

Comment: @PM2Ring , I change the code to the way the comments are saying. It's working now.

Comment: @d-coder If you want to write an answer that improves the OP's code, with explanations, go ahead. You'll probably score an upvote or two. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring : Haha! I just want to help OP just like you guys!

Comment: @d-coder And I'm sure Ace would be very happy if you showed him various ways to improve that code.

Comment: @AceLawson : Please see my answers for few pointers! Cheers! Let me know if you liked or not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print statement in your inner loop for the character selection, is the culprit here, just push it one indentation to the left and it should work.

```
for c in range(length): #for loop which 

    password += random.choice(chars) #randomly choses characters at random to create the password

print(password)
```

just keep it in the `for p in range(3):` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have indented this incorrectly:

```
for p in range(3):

    password = " "

    for c in range(length):#for loop which 

        password += random.choice(chars)#randomly choses characters at random to create the password

        print(password)
```

It should be this:

```
    for p in range(3):

        password = " "

        for c in range(length):#for loop which

            password += random.choice(chars)#randomly choses characters at random to create the password

        print(password)
```

By placing the print statement in the first loop, it will only execute at the end of each iteration of p, rather than each iteration of c.

Answer (score 1):

There is so much things we could help you out here than just what you asked for actually! I'll write same code with your requirements ( assuming I got them all right ) with comments.

```
import random

def generate_password(): #menu function, Generates a password
    # global password           # NOT NEEDED BUT I"M ASSUMING THINGS HERE
    print("Generating...")

    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()?"#These are the avaliable characters available to the password

    length = int(input("password length?")) #asks for how long the user wants their password

    if length <= 26: #Doesn't allow the code to print over 26 characters -> THIS SHOULD BE LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO 26 BC YOU SAID OVER 26 CHARS
        for p in range(3):
            password = " "        # EMPTY STRING.. PYTHON WOULDN'T MIND
            for c in range(length): #for loop which
                password += random.choice(chars) #randomly choses characters at random to create the password -> CONCATENATION HERE.. WE LOVE IT.
            print(password)  # THIS WAS OUT OF PLACE.
    else:
       print ("The password can only be between 8-24 characterss long")
       generate_password ()     # PERFECT!

generate_password()
```

Now after I come with somewhat ok-ish code I can't sleep at night bc I know I can improve it even more if I do it in my way.

```
import random
import string


def generate_password(): #menu function, Generates a password
    print("Generating...")
    try:
        length = int(input("password length?")) #asks for how long the user wants their password
        if 8 <= length < 25:  # Doesn't allow the code to print over 26 characters -> THIS SHOULD BE LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO 26 BC YOU SAID OVER 26 CHARS
            password = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "!@#$%^&*()?") for _ in range(length))    # throw away variable caution here!
            print(password)
        else:
            print("The password can only be between 8-24 characterss long")
            generate_password()  # PERFECT!
    except Exception as e:  # Do some homework on what kind of exception(s) you would like to catch ( like ValueError)
        print(e)
        pass                # Don't just pass it. Do something here depending on the Exception

generate_password()
```

Comment: Ok. There's no need to include the OP's original version in your answer. There are several more things you can do to improve this code. Since you got rid of the `global`, you probably should return the password. It would be good if you got rid of that ugly recursive call to `generate_password()`: don't use recursion when a simple `while` loop can do the job. Maybe add `try...except` logic in case the user doesn't input a number for `length`. And check that `length` isn't less than 8.

Comment: I know. I just carried away with the OP's code. Sorry. I will delete the answer and the comments. I lost my cool.

Comment: There's no need to delete this answer, just improve it a little.

Comment: I did try my best :) But I think you can improve it more!

Comment: @PM2Ring : Thank you so much! Today you made me realize something at deeper level. Cheers!

Comment: I've hidden an alternative version inside a HTML comment. Do whatever you want with it. Note that the OP's version prints 3 passwords of the given length, but I think it's better to just return the password & let the caller call it 3 times if they want 3 passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just move print out of loop:

```
for c in range(length):
    password += random.choice(chars)
print(password)
```

Also you could consider this:

```
password = ''.join([random.choise(chars) for _ in range(length)])
```

Comment: Even better: `''.join([random.choice(chars) for _ in range(length)])`. If you pass `.join` a generator it has to run the generator to create a list before it can start joining. That's because it makes two passes over the data. The 1st pass determines the size of the destination string, the 2nd pass does the actual copying. BTW, in recent versions of Python 3 you can do `''.join(random.choices(chars, k=length))`.